# Area of an ellipse, can't find error

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area, change-of-variable

I'm trying to find the area of an ellipse given by $x^2 - xy + y^2 = 2$.

I am using the mapping $(u, v) = (x-\frac{y}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}y}{2})$, since the ellipse can be written as $(x-\frac y 2) ^2 + \frac {3y^2}{4} = 2$, so $u^2 + v^2 = 2$.

I get that $\frac {\partial (x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} = 2/\sqrt3$

And so my integral would be $\frac {2} {\sqrt{3}} \iint_D u^2 + v^2 du \, dv$.

In polar co-ordinates, this comes to $\frac {2} {\sqrt{3}} \int_0^2 \int_0^{2\pi} r^3 dr \, d\theta = \frac {16\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$.

However, the correct answer is $\frac { 4 \pi } {\sqrt3}$ given here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx#MultInt_Change_Ex4

What is wrong with my method? I'm assuming its something to do with my original mapping because that is where my solution diverges from the one given, but I don't see why my mapping is invalid.

Comment: When does $r$ go to $0$ as limit for polar coordinates?

Comment: Your integral should be $\frac {2}{\sqrt 3} \int_D1\cdot dudv$ where $D=\{(u,v): u^2+v^2\leq 2\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your method and calculations: it's set up correctly, it almost works, and it is fine to use instead of the substitution in the solution given.   But the error happens when you convert to polar coordinates, where you overcompensated for the different radius.

In your case, $u^2+v^2 = 2$, so you have a circle of radius $\sqrt 2$.  So the endpoints of your integral with respect to $r$ should not be 0 and 2, they should be 0 and $\sqrt 2 $.

Comment: By the way, since your Jacobian is constant, you can do this without an integral if you are allowed to use the formula $\pi r^2$ to get $2\pi$ for the area of the circle $u^2+v^2=2$.  Then multiply by your Jacobian $2/\sqrt{3}$ to get $4\pi/\sqrt{3}$. In general problems it's probably better to do the whole integral, and you have to without a constant Jacobian; but this method works for ellipses since they're just linear transformations of circles.

Comment: Thank you, this is a terrible habit of mine, to take the radius as $r^2$ instead of $r$. In general, I would not have taken the integral, but since I was taking my radius as $2$, I was getting the incorrect answer and couldn't figure out why.